# Drupal 7 SmugMug API

Tags: 7

Has there been any work to get SmugMug to work on Drupal 7? I am about to move forward on developing a solution, but wanted to check before I went forward. I do know there was some to work with MediaWorks, but that is a bit of a limited solution and was developed for Drupal 6.

Comment: do you want to pull images from SmugMug or upload them to SmugMug?

Answer (score 0):

2016 and I'm looking into this as well, now with regard to Drupal 8. I'm wondering about hosting the backend of our media assets locally.
The lure of using an external system is to get a more light weight cms and an easier migration path.
Part of our online core is a photo sharing platform similar to facebook's. 
So I need something robust. I can't use Google+ because Google does whatever Google wants to do. I can't use Flickr because I can't be sure that it will be around in 3 years. So Smugmug is a logical candidate.

Anyway, for drupal 7 i found a limited media integration to insert smugmug assets the normal way: https://www.drupal.org/project/media_smugmug .
Smugmug also has an extensive api to program against. https://api.smugmug.com/api/v2/doc